# How to make an meta_query optional?

Tags: php, custom-field, filters, meta-query, rest-api

I added this snippet of code to my `functions.php` to be able to make a request to a custom post type and filter by `book_id`

```
add_filter( 'rest_gallery_query', function( $args ) {
  $args['meta_query'] = array(
    array(
      'key'   => 'book_id',
      'value' => esc_sql( $_GET['book_id'] ),
    )
  );

  return $args;
} );
```

so with that I am able to make a request to 'http://localhost:port/wp-json/wp/v2/gallery?book_id=9780061992254'
`gallery` is a custom post type and `bookd_id` is one of its custom fields

the issue I am having here is after this I can't do requests to `/wp-json/wp/v2/gallery` without `book_id` anymmore and I really need to be able to do it, how can I get rid of that situation?
I was looking for a way to make this param optional but I didn't find anything yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so difficult. All you have to do is to add a condition and check if the `book_id` param is passed. You can even check if this param is correct (for example if the book_id should be a number, then you can check if it is):

```
add_filter( 'rest_gallery_query', function( $args ) {
    if ( trim($_GET['book_id']) ) {  // check if book_id is passed and is not empty, but you can modify this condition
        $args['meta_query'] = array(
            array(
                'key'   => 'book_id',
                'value' => trim( $_GET['book_id'] ),  // <- you don't need to esc_sql this
            )
        );
    }

    return $args;
} );
```

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work, the book_id is still required using your answer

Comment: @WagnerMoreira what do you mean when you write "it is required"? If you don't pass it or you pass an empty string as this param, then no  meta_query will be added. So no - it is not required - it's optional.